# How can I make the left pane extend to the full height of the right pane's content?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make this work for 2 days now and have read many examples and stack overflow questions.  I'm new to html and css, this is my 3rd day.  Any tips or insights into what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated, as well as general comments or criticisms.

I'm trying to make the blue pane on the left side extend the entire length of the page, not just the height of the browser's viewport.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0t9ftrx/)

Thank you

```
#leftPane {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0e365b;
}

#rightPane {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:200px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;  
    width: 900px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `container`, otherwise `leftpane` wouldn't know how much the `rightpane` expands. So with `container` in place, the `container` will expand with `rightpane` and since `leftpane` is child object of `container` it gets the `height` of it when set to `100%` with some appropriate positioning.

```css
/* Lightest Blue:   #4096e5   (nav boxes)
   Darker Blue:   #195e9f    (nav boxes roll over)
   Darker Blue:   #043d71  (children roll over)
   Darkest Blue:   #0e365b   (left pane)
   
   Off-white:    #EEEEEE  (right pane background)
*/

* {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}
#leftPane {
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
}
#leftPane > p {
  margin: 10px;
}
#leftPane {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0e365b;
}
#leftPane h1,
h2,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000;
}
#rightPane {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 900px;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 40px;
}
#nav {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 5;
}
#nav li,
ul {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#nav a:link,
a:visited,
.top {
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #4096e5;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
#nav a.top:link,
a.top:visited,
.top {
  width: 180px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav a.sub:link,
a.sub:visited {
  text-align: left;
}
#nav .divider {
  border-right: 1px black dashed;
}
#nav a:hover,
span:hover {
  background-color: #195e9f;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #043d71;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#nav ul li {
  background: #195e9f;
  float: none;
  border-top: 1px black dashed;
}
#nav ul a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
#nav li:hover a,
li:hover span {
  /* These create persistent hover states, meaning the top-most link
    stays 'hovered' even when your cursor has moved down the list. */
  background: #195e9f;
}
#nav li:hover ul a {
  /* The persistent hover state does however create a global style for
    links even before they're hovered. Here we undo these effects. */
  text-decoration: none;
}
#mainContent {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="leftPane">
      <h2>Title<br>Section</h2>
      <p>some more text, this should wrap.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="rightPane">
      <div id="header">
        <ul id="nav">
          <li>
            <span class="top divider">Projects</span>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="sub lastA" href="#">One</a>
              </li>
              <li><a class="sub lastA" href="#">Two</a>
              </li>
              <li><a class="sub lastA" href="#section3">Three</a>
              </li>
              <li><a class="sub lastA" href="#">Four</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="top divider">Examples</span>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="sub lastA" href="#">Data Structures</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a class="top" href="#">Blog</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="mainContent">
        There are a few interesting things here that should be noted.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <a name="section3">Begin Section 3</a>
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
        <br>.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I thought `body` was already acting as that container?  Thank you for your help.  This is a step closer to what I want, but there is still some extra space at the top and bottom as seen here:  http://jsfiddle.net/m0t9ftrx/3/  I'm trying to figure this out on my own as well but if you know how to remove that top and bottom excess I'd appreciate it.

Comment: My problem was #mainContent{position:absolute}.  I discovered this by inspecting the elements in firefox.  Here is the solution:  http://jsfiddle.net/m0t9ftrx/5/    Thanks again.

Comment: I played around css so much that I changed most of the stuff, then I used fresh snippet to change only required css and completely forgot about extra spaces. Good thing you solved those, Nice work.

Answer (score 3):

Well the problem is, all your elements(leftpane, rightpane, header and mainContent) are positioned *absolute*. **Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow** and positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than *static* (in this case, "html").

[hint: open firebug and check *layout* of your page. "body" is not getting any height.]

[image]

Thats why providing height:100% is giving default *height of the container* and not *full height of document*

**Solution:**

As @Prachit answered above, a legitimate fix would be to *enclose your absolutely positioned elements in a relatively positioned container* and since **relatively positioned elements are positioned relative to their normal position**,

- It'll be preserved in the normal flow. So, now giving height:100%
  would provide height of the document and not the container itself.
- (absolutely positioned)leftpane, would now know how much height
  rightpane is getting[since both of them would be taking height of
  their parent container].

You may get more insight on positioning from [this](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) tutorial.

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Refer here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671012/extend-div-height-to-entire-webpage)

```
<div><!-- make a <div> to hold everything in.. -->

<div style="width:125;height:100%;">blah blah blah</div>

<div style="height:100%;">blah blah blah</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I was not aware of the extra div needed, I thought the body tag was capable of being the parent.